# JLPT N3 Practice Grammar 2 ついた

Tags: jlpt

From #5 of 日本語能力試験３級の模擬試験　-文法２- (http://jlpt.u-biq.org/3g2.html)

> 5）「今 どこに いますか。」「（　　）。」

**A) えきに ついた ところです**

 B) えきに ついている ところです

 C) えきに ついた 時です　　　　

 D) えきに ついている 時です

Answer is A. I don't understand how ついた is used here?

Answer (score 4):

えきに ついた ところです means "I have just arrived at the station". 着く{つく} means "arrive". た is a verbal auxiliary which indicates "completion".

つく written in kanji are many like 付く, 突く, 就く etc and they have different  meaning.